# Making charts in ASP.NET with Flot and get the values from code-behind file

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, flot

I'm working on a project were I have input from the user from the ASP.NET page. This input is then being processed into data and with this data I can create charts, this works with the Microsoft standard Charting library's.

But now I want to make the same chart but with Flot. I can make a Flot chart but this data is hard-coded in the .ASPX page. This is with jQuery.

What I'm trying to do is let the code-behind file fill in the chart. I know I need to use JSON (which I'm not acquainted with), but I don't know how.

Comment: I don't know what this line means:
"What I'm trying to do is let de code-behind file the chart. I know I need to use JSON (which I'm not acquainted with), but I wont succeed."
Can you try to clarify that? I understand that English is likely not your native language and will work with you to understand the problem.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7168338/1263389) what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is to use AJAX do load data dynamically from a server.

Here is an example to do as much.

http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/ajax.html

Let me know if this is not that for which you are looking.

Comment: Zéychin that's exacltly how I want it, although I have al ready found this file, I want to know how can I put the data from a C# file to JSON to the FLOT chart.