# Serialize class type to JSON?

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I would like a JSON representation of my classes type so I can plug them into a client-side schema. This is how my server-side C# class looks like:

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }

    public bool IsMarried { get; set; }
}
```

How do I serialize it to this?:

```
{
    fields: {
        "ID": {
            type: "number"
        },
        "Name": {
            type: "string",
            validation: {
                required: true,
                message: "Name is required.",
            }
        },
        "Birthday": {
            type: "date"
        },
        "IsMarried": {
            type: "bool"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the JavaScript tag? You want to do this on the server, right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167950/how-to-serialize-from-c-sharp-to-json-a-list-containing-a-list-containing-an-arr

Comment: Are you trying to create json schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't anything (AFAIK) ready-made for that in the JSON.NET library, but it's fairly simple to implement it using some reflection code:

```
public class StackOverflow_19336832
{
    public class RequiredAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required.")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }

        public bool IsMarried { get; set; }
    }

    static JObject GetSchema(Type type)
    {
        var result = new JObject();
        foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties())
        {
            var name = prop.Name;
            var propType = prop.PropertyType;
            var field = new JObject();
            result.Add(name, field);
            switch (Type.GetTypeCode(propType))
            {
                case TypeCode.Boolean:
                    field.Add("type", "bool");
                    break;
                case TypeCode.Int16:
                case TypeCode.Int32:
                case TypeCode.Int64:
                case TypeCode.UInt16:
                case TypeCode.UInt32:
                case TypeCode.UInt64:
                case TypeCode.Double:
                case TypeCode.Single:
                    field.Add("type", "number");
                    break;
                case TypeCode.String:
                    field.Add("type", "string");
                    break;
                case TypeCode.DateTime:
                    field.Add("type", "date");
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException("Don't know how to generate schema for property with type " + propType.FullName);
            }

            var req = prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RequiredAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault() as RequiredAttribute;
            if (req != null)
            {
                var validation = new JObject();
                field.Add("validation", validation);
                validation.Add("required", true);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(req.ErrorMessage))
                {
                    validation.Add("message", req.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        var schema = GetSchema(typeof(Person));
        Console.WriteLine(schema);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is JsonSchemaGenerator which will create a JsonSchema from a type. You can then ToString() the JsonSchema to get its JSON - http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/AllMembers_T_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema_JsonSchemaGenerator.htm

Answer (score -1):

Have a look here for some ideas on how to use `JavaScriptSerializer` to get the job done. There are other serializers as well but this one works well and the link offers examples of how to implement and use it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx

Comment: The OP is trying to create a JSON schema from his class definition, not serialize an instance of the class.  The link you cited does not demonstrate how you would use the JavaScriptSerializer to do this.